# How to see previous output in terminal window?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, logs, output, mate-desktop

I was running a lengthy scientific simulation (which took almost a week to run) on my Linux workstation with the command which looked like this:

`time ./simulation`

So besides getting the output files from the simulation my aim was to also get the exact time it took to run this simulation. However, unfortunately, I ran the command `ls -la` before copying the time output, but my terminal window only shows a limited number of lines. So I have now changed the number of lines to unlimited in the terminal settings, but I still can't scroll up to see the time information. Is there a way to see that information without having to re-run the simulation?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Are you using a multiplexer such as `tmux` or `screen`?

Comment: So, just to confirm, you do know how to scroll back in your terminal, but the output of `ls -la` was longer than the configured number of lines and pushed _everything_ out?

Comment: Can you get the time from auxiliary data, e.g. the start of the process is the last access time of the simulation's config file or input, and the finish time is the modification timestamp of its output? (This would tell you the wall clock time only, not the user/sys times.)

Comment: @Panki I'm using MATE Terminal 1.20.

Comment: @egmont That is correct.

Comment: @egmont Yes, it is possible to get the clock time, not the other two times (the simulation was run on multiple cores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can no longer access those lines in mate-terminal.

Increasing the number of scrollback lines doesn't help either: The terminal doesn't remember all the lines and reveals only the configured amount; it remembers only the configured amount.

---

That being said, if the given terminal tab is still open, there's still some chance that the data wasn't actually overwritten and is recoverable through deep investigation; similarly to how deleted files can still be recovered from disk if they weren't actually overwritten. The chance of succeeding decreases by every additional line that was scrolled out, i.e. if the data scrolled out by 5 lines, it's most likely recoverable, if it scrolled out by millions of lines then most likely it was overwritten.

(If you closed the given terminal tab, it's hopeless to recover the data: it's stored on the disk in an encrypted file, and the encryption key is zeroed out in the memory when the terminal is closed.)

Such an investigation requires understanding VTE's scrollback handling, digging into the memory and open files of the terminal process, and carefully examining these data. It would probably take days of heavy work, with no guarantee. Having access to the entire raw drive slightly further increases the chance, although significantly increases the required time, and makes it problematic to do it remotely.

If it was about some highly critical data (e.g. password to your bitcoin wallet containing your life savings), you could start studying VTE's internals and do this investigation, or hire someone (e.g. me) to do this for you. Given that it's "just" a week of running something, it's highly unlikely to be worth it for you, it's cheaper just to re-run the thing.

(Note: I wrote most of the code handling VTE's (i.e. mate-terminal's) scrollback buffer.)